# How can I set and update the the_date according to a custom field of the post

Tags: posts, custom-field, date

How can I set and update the `the_date` according to a custom field of the post?

I have a custom field "date-time" with the following format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

e.g. 2015-09-30 08:12

I'd like this date to over-ride the normal date and time of the post, both on publish and when updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would write a function that gets called by the `save_post` hook, and use `wp_update_post` to update the post. The problem is, when you call `wp_update_post` it calls `save_post`, which will cause an infinite loop.

To get around that, we will unhook our function before calling `wp_update_post`, then re-hook it afterward.

I have not tried this, but it should work:

```
function change_post_date( $post_id, $post ) {

    // WordPress calls "save_post" when a post is saved, updated, autosaved,
    // revision created, or ajax called. We only want to execute this function
    // during post save and update. The next 3 "if" statements check to see why
    // save_post was called...

    // Autosave? Do nothing
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    // AJAX? Do nothing
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
        return;
    // Post revision? Do nothing
    if ( false !== wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    // Make sure the person editing the post has permission to do so
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    // Get the "date-time" field
    $date_time_field = get_post_meta($post_id, 'date-time', true);

    // Unhook
    remove_action('save_post', 'change_post_date', 10);

    $args = array (
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_date' => $date_time_field,
        'post_date_gmt' => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', $date_time_field )
    );

    wp_update_post( $args );

    // Re-hook
    add_action('save_post', 'change_post_date', 10);

}
add_filter('save_post', 'change_post_date', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks heaps. I've looked everywhere for this. Hopefully this will help others

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad it helped!

Comment: And very well outlayed and commented

Comment: Whoops, sorry. It doesn't work .

Comment: I updated the code. Try again? And are you getting a specific error? (You may need to enable WP_DEBUG)

Comment: OK it does work but here's the thing... I'm using the front end posting plugin WP User Frontend Pro and you need to hook it into the plugin if you post using it. Your code works fine from the back end...    http://docs.wedevs.com/using-action-hook-field/

Comment: I haven't used that plugin before, but it looks like you'll also need to call the change_post_date function with the wpuf_add_post_after_insert and wpuf_edit_post_after_update hooks. You may also need to unhook and re-hook them, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wanna have a go? :)